# What happens if I keep the "margin" blank without even putting semicolon to it?

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive

```
 #header {
        margin:                      *<--This one*
        position: fixed;
        width:100%;
        background-color: black;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        overflow: auto;
        margin:0 auto;
        display: block;
    }
```

I am building a **website** in which I encountered that the `<h1>` element goes behind the fixed navbar. I tried to find the optimal solution for this.

I figured out that many people made an extra `<div1>` container which had the same height as that of the navbar and then used another `<div2>` element to write whatever they have to show to the user.

I had a problem with this solution actually my navbar is a responsive one. So I have to make the `<div1>`  element responsive too, using `@media`.

Then experimenting with margin I found that leaving the margin blank gives me the optimal one. It doesn't requires me to add the `<div1>` container.

I found this helpful. Since I am newbie in Programming, I don't know if these type of shortcuts are not good to be used.

P.S. I used "Brackets" editor and the live preview was shown in Google Chrome.

edit: the `#header` is the container for the navbar and is fixed. `position:fixed`.

Comment: Leaving margin blank is also not letting your posiion:fixed; style o be applied! May be your issue is with how fixed is working in your code. Please post a snippet so that we can help you with a cleaner solution. Check the computed styles    https://ibb.co/iKYnho. Try setting position:relative; z-index:10; on the h1 element

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma You were Correct, I couldn't fix the navbar. But then as you told to put my code, do I need to put both HTML and CSS code??And what is that link which you added in your comment. How do I use the link to correct my code , like the way you did and checked the code?? Thank you.

Comment: That link is judt an image showing that fixed property is not working. You can put your code either in stackoverflow only or create a fiddle for the same and post the url here

Comment: Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/Amar_newDev/9vrud5yq/   . Please forgive me if there is too much of Chaos in understanding the code. I haven't put comments anywhere.

Comment: What exactly do you want to be fixed. Can you please tell again, ques is too long,give the gist if possible

Comment: Did you see the "id=nav-bar" . I want to fix the navigation bar but also make it responsive to the size of the window.

Comment: Added an answer. Please look into it. Will give its explanation in 10-15 mins. Busy right now. Thanks

Comment: Did you check my answer? I updated it a bit more. please check

Answer (score 0):

It causes everything until the next `;` to be treated as invalid and dropped.

It is not a shortcut, it is a longer way to achieve the same effect as not typing `margin: position: fixed;` at all.

Answer (score 0):

CSS was designed to be very forgiving of errors. There are multiple reasons for this.

Imagine you're using a background-gradient which older browsers might not understand. Your whole CSS code would break.
That's why CSS just continues with the next statement that it can find. For example:

```
.foo {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

CSS reads the file top to bottom, so first the black background shall be applied and after that the gradient background will be applied. Which will lead to a red/yellowish background in modern browsers.

Without CSS error handling our whole CSS would die in old browsers.

In your case however, CSS reads the following statement:

```
 #header {
        margin: position: fixed;
}
```

Which is an syntax error and neither of those will be applied. CSS will just continue with your `width: 100%` statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a fixed header, you should give margin-top to the next element that is equal to the height of the fixed header, so that it starts after the fixed element. But this will work only if your header is of fixed height. In case your header is not of a fixed height and changes with viewport then add a resize function on body that calculates the height of header on each resize and gives the same value as marginTop to the next element after the fixed element.

```css
 
body{
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
top : 0;
position: fixed;
width:100%;
background-color: black;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
overflow: auto;
height: 65px;
}
#nav-bar a{
display: block;
padding: 9px 16px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
color:azure;
text-decoration:none;
}
#nav-bar a:hover{
background-color: rgba(49, 248, 23, 0.94);
}
.nav-right{
float:right;
font-size: 17px;
text-align: center;
}
@media(max-width:600px){
#nav-bar{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    
    
}
.nav-right{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
}
.logo {
font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
font-size: 30px;
}

#header-img {
height:35px;
width:30px; 
}

h2 {
text-align: center;
background: linear-gradient(0deg,red,yellow);
padding: 14px;
}

#form {
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
margin-bottom: 21px;
}

#email {
height: 21px;
width: 250px;
border-radius: 3px;
border-color: #938e8e;
}

section {
position: relative;
top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The Bookworms Site</title>
<link href="style-sheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes|Limelight" rel="stylesheet"> 
  </head>
  <body onresize="myFunction()">
  
 
<main>
  <header id="header">
<div id="nav-bar">
    <a href="#Works" class="logo"><img src="book.jpg" id="header-img"> The Bookworms Site</a>
    <div class="nav-right">
        <a href="#About">About</a>
        <a href="#Features">Features</a>
        <a href="#Pricing">Pricing</a>
    </div>
</div>
  </header>
<div id="abc" style="margin-top: 65px;"> 
    <h2> Hurry!! Offers until Next 20 Hours!!</h2>
    <form id="form">
        <section>Email:</section>
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
        <button type="submit" url="">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </main>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById( "abc").style.marginTop = document.getElementById( "header").clientHeight + "px"
       
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Actually you have used <script> to which I am unknown and also I have no idea about "function". I figured out by myself https://jsfiddle.net/Amar_newDev/9vrud5yq/2/ . By the Way, thanks for all your help, you were a great teacher.

Comment: You should know about javascript too . If you are building a website, sooner or later you will have to learn it. M saying this as an advice, start reading/learning javascript. Will help you a lot in future :)